# Submit button not working from within an iframe in IE

Tags: iframe, form-submit

I'm a very hunt/copy/paste kind of guy when it comes to the backend so please excuse the underbelly if it is disgusting :)

Here's the lowdown: I've made a "one-page" style website and each sub-section is an iframe which you can see here: [website](http://www.danielwheeler.net)

The problem is: The Contact section in IE. It too is an iframe with drw-mailform.php in it.  I can not get the Submit button to work when inside the iframe, BUT when I type it directly, www.danielwheeler.net/drw-mailform.php, the form works just fine.  So, something about the iframe is messing with me and after tons of google attempts I have yet to find out why.

index-ie.html code is: (Ok, sorry. I can't seem to copy/paste the code from Dreamweaver here without it being an unformatted block of mess?)

drw-mailform.php code called into iframe is:

```
<style type="text/css">
label{font:1em arial,helvetica,sans-serif;color:#663300}
a{color:#663300;text-decoration:none;outline:none;}
a:hover{color:#663300;}
body{background-color:transparent;}
</style>

<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send-form-email.php">

<table width="387" height="396" align="center"  cellspacing="10"     background="img/contact_bg.jpg" style="background-repeat:no-repeat;">
<tr>
<td height="66" colspan="2" valign="top">
<label for="first_name"></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="121" valign="top"><label for="first_name">First Name *</label></td>
<td width="230" valign="top"><input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50"    size="30" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"">
<label for="last_name">Last Name *</label> </td>
<td valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="26" valign="top">
<label for="email">Email *</label></td>
<td valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="101" valign="top">
<label for="comments">Comments *</label> </td>
<td valign="top"><textarea  name="comments" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="75" colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
<input type="submit" value="Send"> </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Well, hopefully this is enough to offer me some help.  Thanks to all that try :)

Answer (score -1):

First off, there are very, very few reasons to use an iframe. In fact, it is generally highly discouraged in web design unless it is absolutely necessary. Looking at your site, I see no reason to be using iframes. I would suggest getting rid of your iframes, utilize the generally accepted method for accomplishing whatever the reason is you're using iframes, and rebuild those pieces. iframes are bad for any number of reasons, I highly recommend not using them.

Comment: I'm not saying iframes are bad, per se, but the misuse of iframes (an all too common ocurance) is definitely bad.